# If a gidget is identified by a combination of parameters should I have all the parameters everywhere in the DB or only once?

Tags: mysql, database-design

For example: An object of clothing is uniquely identified by its style, color, accessories, and size.

In the inventory I need to know which object is being referenced, and how many I have in stock.
I'll also need that information for the shopping carts, invoices, order confirmations, etc.

Should I have those 5 tables each with

```
id (int)
style (varchar)
color (varchar)
accessories (varchar)
size (varchar)
quantity(int)
```

Or, should I have a 'Unique Garment' table plus 5 tables that reference it? Like this

```
id (int)
style (varchar)
color (varchar)
accessories (varchar)
size (varchar)
```

and

```
id (int)
garment (int)
quantity (int)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on whether you need to track individual items. If you do, then your UniqueItem table should have something like a SerialNumber column as well which actually identifies it. If you aren't interested in individual items (clue: usually you're not) then no need to have a row for each; go with your first guess.